# Draw picture using PSTricks

Tags: floats, pstricks, pspicture

I am using MikTex and Texmaker, and the configurations-LaTeX+dvips+ps2pdf+View PDF.
I have the following latex commands:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(4,4.3)
    \rput(3.7,-0.2){\scalebox{1.2}{
       \psdot(1.5,3.5)\rput(1.45,3.75){$v_1$}
       \psdot(-1,2)\rput(-1.3,2){$v_2$}
       \psdot(.5,2.3)\rput(0.9,2.3){$v_3$}
       \psdot(3,1)\rput(3,0.7){$v_4$}
       \psdot(4,2)\rput(4.3,2){$v_5$}
       \psdot(1,0.5)\rput(1,0.2){$v_6$}
       \psline(1.5,3.5)(-1,2)
       \psline(1.5,3.5)(0.5,2.3)
       \psline(1.5,3.5)(3,1)
       \psline(1.5,3.5)(1,0.5)
       \psline(-1,2)(.5,2.3)
       \psline(-1,2)(1,0.5)
       \psline(-1,2)(4,2)
       \psline(3,1)(.5,2.3)
       \psline(4,2)(3,1)
       \psline(-1,2)(1,0.5)
    }
  \end{pspicture}
  \caption{The graph $G_1$}\label{Fig-1}
\end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

The figure doesn't appear when I try to run the source file. The following error appears:

```
!LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.
```

However, there is no two `\documentclass` used as warned.
Please help me troubleshoot.

Comment: Here is an error here: `$G_1}` and there is a missing `}` after the brace that closes `\scalebox`. There is an extra `}` after `\end{figure}`. Then it compiles for me. What is the intention of that `\scalebox`?

Comment: is your document called `pstricks.tex` (don't do that)

Comment: My actual problem seems that \begin{pspicture}...\end{pspicture} is not recognised in my system.

Comment: `pspicture` won't be defined as that error means you never input the pstricks code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that your document is called `pstricks.tex` and your log looks like:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex))))
(./pstricks.tex

! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \documentclass[11pt]{
                         article}
?
```

The problem is that `pstricks.sty` is a latex wrapper for a plain tex file `pstricks.tex` so if your document is called `pstricks.tex` when you have `\usepackage{pstricks}` it ends up doing `\input pstricks.tex`  and instead of finding the pstricks code, it re-inputs your document and you get the two documentclass error.

Just rename your document file to anything else.

If the document is renamed that part of the log/terminal output is:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
```

showing that the real `pstricks.tex` from `texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex` has been loaded.

Comment: I have changed the file name to "Drawpicture". However, new error appears in line 1: ! File ended while scanning use of \pst@makenoteverbbox<inserted text>...

Comment: @gete yes you have an incorect `}` in the code see the other answer. This answer relates to the error shown in the question which is unrelated to any specifc pspicture it occurs during package loading before the document starts.

Comment: There is a test in `pstricks.sty` for a second `\documentclass`,  but it seems that it no more works ...

Comment: @user187802 that sounds  familiar..I should check

Comment: @user187802 I see the problem, I'll open an issue at pstricks with a fix

Answer (score 2):

Grouping was wrongly done, modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(4,4.3)
    \rput(3.7,-0.2){\scalebox{1.2}{
       \psdot(1.5,3.5)\rput(1.45,3.75){$v_1$}
       \psdot(-1,2)\rput(-1.3,2){$v_2$}
       \psdot(.5,2.3)\rput(0.9,2.3){$v_3$}
       \psdot(3,1)\rput(3,0.7){$v_4$}
       \psdot(4,2)\rput(4.3,2){$v_5$}
       \psdot(1,0.5)\rput(1,0.2){$v_6$}
       \psline(1.5,3.5)(-1,2)
       \psline(1.5,3.5)(0.5,2.3)
       \psline(1.5,3.5)(3,1)
       \psline(1.5,3.5)(1,0.5)
       \psline(-1,2)(.5,2.3)
       \psline(-1,2)(1,0.5)
       \psline(-1,2)(4,2)
       \psline(3,1)(.5,2.3)
       \psline(4,2)(3,1)
       \psline(-1,2)(1,0.5)
    }}
  \end{pspicture}
  \caption{The graph $G_1$}\label{Fig-1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: yes that's a later error in the pstricks code, but not responsible for the two documentclass error shown which happens as the package is loaded not related to any specific pspicture

Answer (score 1):

run with `lualatex --shell-escape <your file>`. Then it can calculate the frame of the image. And use nodes, makes live easier:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\psset{calcframe}
\begin{pspicture}%
\pnodes{v}(0,0)(1.5,3.5)(-1,2)(0.5,2.3)(3,1)(4,2)(1,0.5)
\pspolygon[showpoints](v5)(v4)(v3)(v2)(v1)(v6)(v2)   
\pspolygon[showpoints](v3)(v1)(v4)   
\uput[90](v1){$v_1$}\uput[180](v2){$v_2$}\uput[0](v3){$v_3$}
\uput[-90](v4){$v_4$}\uput[0](v5){$v_5$}\uput[-90](v6){$v_6$}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{The graph $G_1$}\label{Fig-1}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]